# Updating DocumentStencil to real draw in Visio with C#

Tags: c#, visio, stencils

One of the features that is shown in Visio is the DocumentStencil. Everytime you add an object in your Visio Draw, the DocumentStencil created this object automatically so its easy to use afterwards. The problem is that when this object is deleted and there are not more objects like this in the draw the DocumentStencil do not get Updated deleting the object that do not exist anymore. Below I attach code to show which is the toolbar that I talking about.

> ```
> axDrawingControl1.Document.Application.DoCmd((int)VisUICmds.visCmdHideDocumentStencil);
> ```

Comment: You have made a true statement.  Is there a question to go along with it?

Comment: I have discovered that is like this. What I would like is to get into this Document Stencil and make visible objects or not depending on my choice but I think its not possible. I have added a new Windows bar.Thanks anyway!